# Import a list of emails (.csv), cycle through each email and provide appropriate Get-ADuser properties and export

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, scripting

I've got a situation where I need to take a list of emails in a .csv, import the list and pull the applicable properties from Active Directory (via GetAD-User?).

**Below is my estimated process flow:**

1. Import a .csv list of emails
2. Use a loop to iterate through each line.
3. Pipe the data to Get-ADUser (via -filter) and return the appropriate properties.

**Here is a sample list for testing purposes (Saved As: csv_file.csv):**

```
abc@abc.com
1abc@abc.com
a2bc@abc.com
a3bc@abc.com
a4bc@abc.com
ab5c@abc.com
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    $Name = @()

    Get-Content -path "C:\Location\Of\Sample\Input\csv_file.csv" |

    ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADuser  -filter * -properties 
    Mail, DisplayName, Department, Office | Select DisplayName, Department, 
    Office
}
```

When I run this, I receive a list of ALL AD Users, for each email line listed in my sample csv_file.csv.

**My Issue:**
1. How do I only show the users whose Mail property is listed in my csv file? For example, I have 6 emails listed, I should show the properties associated with only those 6 addresses. 
2. How do I compare the value listed in the .csv to the .Mail property within Get-ADUser?

**Example Output:**
Over 60k+ DisplayName, Department, Office records!

I seem to have difficulty understanding the looping constraints and filters within powershell. I'm certain the root of my issue is -filter *, but what should it be? How do I iterate through each address appropriately? I've referenced a few other posts but cannot seem to identify anything specific to this situation. 
Constructive criticism is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code snipped appears to be incomplete (?).

Comment: @ s-m-e,  Hmm. Sorry. I think the issue is the break after the -properties entry. Please delete that line break and run the properties on the same line? After doing so, it appears to work once the appropriate file path is given.

Comment: Are you running Exchange?

Comment: @ mjolinor. Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the results you're seeking. One thing to note is that I've used 'EmailAddress' instead of 'Mail' and then filtered on the current EmailAddress.

```
Get-Content -path "C:\Location\Of\Sample\Input\csv_file.csv" | 

ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -eq $emailAddress' -Properties Department, DisplayName, EmailAddress | Select-Object DisplayName, Department, Office
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I appreciate your assistance!
When I tried your query, I receive an error message stating:

Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Object[]'.
Parameter name: mail
At line:6 char:5

Any ideas? I don't even see the parameter: mail,  listed anywhere?

Comment: Could you share your updated code? It seems to suggest that perhaps you may still have 'mail' where you should have 'EmailAddress'.

Comment: Hi Robert, please disregard the Mail comment listed above. I was attempting to troubleshoot further and ended up scrapping the script and going directly back to your recommendation. 

Now, I ran your recommended code but receive the following error:
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'emailAddress' found in expression: $emailAddress is not defined.
At line:6 char:21

With that being said, I thought that maybe it is because $emailAddress is not declared anywhere? I added $emailAddress = @() to create a blank array and now receive the error:

Comment: Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Object[]'.
Parameter name: mail
At line:6 char:21

Comment: The code I am using is: 

$Name = @()
$EmailAddress = @()
Get-Content -path "C:\List\csv_file.csv" |

ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -eq $emailAddress' -Properties Department, DisplayName, EmailAddress | Select-Object DisplayName, Department, Office
}

My sample file is listed as emails, one on each line (with no header):
abc@abc.com
1abc@abc.com
a2bc@abc.com
a3bc@abc.com
a4bc@abc.com
ab5c@abc.com

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't overlooked the lack of header. I think I must have added one to my sample file. If you have only the one column and no header, try this:

`Get-Content -path "C:\List\csv_file.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -eq $_' -Properties Department, DisplayName, EmailAddress | Select-Object DisplayName, Department, Office }`

Comment: Wonderful. I ran the recommendation and it generated exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much for your persistence. Do you have a recommendation on any training material that may benefit in learning this stuff? 

Once again, I am very appreciative of your help

Comment: You're welcome. I have been really enjoying PowerShell for the past few years and hope you will as well. I recommend any materials by Jeffrey Snover and/or Don Jones. There are some good books but I like the accessibility of the YouTube playlist for the Companion Video (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6D474E721138865A) of Don's book PowerShell in a Month of Lunches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Exchange, this will be much quicker:

```
Get-Content -path "C:\Location\Of\Sample\Input\csv_file.csv" |
  Get-Recipient |
  Select DisplayName,Department,Office
```

AD does not use email address as an indexed identity reference, so it has to search the entire directory for every address it cycles through.  Exchange does, and maintains it's own user database with email address as an index, so it can ingest the email address directly, without needing to filter. The `Get-Recipient` cmdlet returns objects that contain the properties you're looking for.

Comment: @ Mjolinor, Thank you for that walkthrough. When I attempted to run the command, I receive an error stating 'Get-Recipient' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.  Perhaps our organization is not using Exchange?

Comment: You need to run it from an Exchange management shell, or via a remote management session.  If you're not sure if you're running Exchange, ask your email administrator.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll reach out to my admin to see if this is a possibility.